# What does it mean for a timezone offset be greater than 12 hours?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, utc, timezone-offset

MySQL chokes from the output of my `getOffset()` function for only these eight timezones.

What does it mean for a timezone offset be greater than 12 hours?  How would you recommend modifying so that `$os` remains between +/- 12 hours?

```
function getOffset() {
    $os=(new \DateTime())->getOffset();
    return $os >= 0?'+'.gmdate("G:i", $os):'-'.gmdate("G:i", -$os);
}


foreach(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() as $tz) {
    date_default_timezone_set($tz);
    $os=getOffset();
    $hours=explode(':',$os)[0];
    if($hours>12 || $hours<-12) {
        echo("$tz has offset of $os.<br>");
    }
}
```

output:

```
Antarctica/McMurdo has offset of +13:00.
Pacific/Apia has offset of +14:00.
Pacific/Auckland has offset of +13:00.
Pacific/Chatham has offset of +13:45.
Pacific/Enderbury has offset of +13:00.
Pacific/Fakaofo has offset of +13:00.
Pacific/Kiritimati has offset of +14:00.
Pacific/Tongatapu has offset of +13:00.
```

Comment: [This has already been reported in 2011](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63685). You gotta love Oracle, they destroy everything they touch :)

Comment: @AlexKarshin  `Pacific/Kiritimati` was actually the one I initially stumbled upon by chance!  So, greater than 13 hours is valid but just not supported by MySQL?  By the way, I am using MariaDB.  Still curious what it means to be over 12 hours, but really a question for a different forum.  Guess the workaround will be to subtract 24 hours.

Comment: The day has 24hs. Form offset 0  you can be upto 12 hours ahead or 12 hours behind. So +13 would be the same as -11.

Comment: @Juan -11 is not the same as +13. It is because of the "International Date Line" where the date changes... 23:00 GMT -11hours is still the same day, but 23:00 GMT +13 is next day... See [intl date line wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Date_Line) Have a look at the map there where the Kiritimati are.

Comment: @Zimmi You are right, though it is something that seems to be artificially introduced by replacing offsets -10 and -11 with +13 and +14. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B14:00.

Comment: Offsets with an absolute value greater than 12 are for countries that want to be on the "other" side of the date line from where they would be if they went strictly by longitude.